# Create two new input fields with input placeholder text with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have a script that creates one input field with the class `"name-number-field"`.

However I want a script that creates two input fields that have `display: inline` and both input fields have placeholder text inside the fields.

Here is what I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.product-quantity').each(function() {
    $(this).data('val', this.value);
}).on('change', function () {
            var val = $(this).val(),
                    old = $(this).data('val'),
                    ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find
                           ('[data-size="'+this.name+'"]'),
                    inc = val >= old;

            if (inc) {
                $('<input/>', {'class': 'name-number-field',  
                     'type':'text'}).insertAfter(ele);
            }else {
                $('.name-number-field', ele.parent()).first().remove();
            }

            $(this).data('val', this.value);
        });
 });
```

I tried to this:

```
$('<input/> <input/>', {'class': 'name-number-field', 'type': 'text'}).insertAfter(ele);
```

it creates two fields, but the script I have does not remove them when I add a second input. I am assuming because the second input doesn't have a class of `"name-number-field"`.

Maybe I could include both the inputs inside a div class `"name-number-field"`, and then remove that entire div class?

I am just not sure how this is suppose to look.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by creating a variable with the created div and inserting html inside that newly created div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.product-quantity').each(function() {
    $(this).data('val', this.value);
}).on('change', function () {
            var val = $(this).val(),
                    old = $(this).data('val'),
                    ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find('[data-
size="'+this.name+'"]'),
                    input = $('<div/> ', {'class': 'name-number-field', 'type': 
'text'}).html('<input class=​"field" type=​"text"><input class=​"field" type=​"text">​'),
                    inc = val >= old;

            if (inc) {
                $(input).insertAfter(ele);
            }else {
                $('.name-number-field', ele.parent()).first().remove();
            }

            $(this).data('val', this.value);
        });
});
```